# SSH server stops responding every couple of days

Tags: debian, sshd

I have an always-on mini pc running debian bullseye. I run several services on the machine including dlna and a shadowsocks server plus tvheadend.

Every two days the ssh server suddenly stops responding. In fact SSHD on port 22 and Tvheadend on port 9981 both stop responding, however i can connect to other services on the machine. (shadowsocks on port 1080 and privoxy on port 8118) both continue to work while ssh is not accessible.

I have checked systemd logs but there are no errors related to systemd or tvheadend or memory problems.

Also i created a cronjob to reboot the server every day at 5:00 am but it seems that none of these help.

Comment: Check the logs (in `/var/log`, probably in `syslog` or `daemon.log`, without `systemd` tools). Usually processes leave some information behind that can help you track the issue. Also, it is very important to know if the `ssh` service stops responding (listening) or stops running. A `ps` or `ss -l` (interactively or via cron) will let you know that. Check other related packages, like a firewall, fail2ban, ...

Comment: I looked up "error" but there are nothing related to ssh in syslog. Will check daemon.log too.

Comment: You might need to actually follow and read the log around the time `ssh` stops. Just looking up `error` would miss things with valuable information on the issue, say, something like `Out of Memory: Killed process 453 (sshd).`.